# What power cord for 5V / 5A power supply

Tags: power-supply

I am rather new to electrical engineering topics.

I am currently building an audio player with multiple components (Raspberry Pi, Amplifier, LEDs, etc.) that all need 5V and all together will never exceed 5 A (actually 4). That’s why I though about getting a [RS-25-5 power supply](http://www.meanwell.com/mw_search/RS-25/RS-25-spec.pdf) and build it right into the case.

My question is: What type of power cord do I need to feed the power supply OR/AND how much current will the power supply draw – will it be up to 5?

I’d love to be able to use a smaller power cord C7/C8 (rated for 2.5 Amps) instead of the huge C13/C14 (rated for 10 Amps) cable socket combo.

I am living in the EU. My wall socket provides 230V and maxes at 16A.

Comment: Are you talking about the power cord for 230 V ? You can use a small 2.5 A power cord on the 230 V side, only the 5 V side will have the 5 A !  On the 230 V side the current will be only: Output Power = 5 V * 5 A = 25 W, 25 W / 230 V = 0.11 A  much less than 2.5 A so you can use the smaller power cord, no worries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take a closer look at the specifications you linked to.

Output current is up to 5Amperes at5Volts.

Input is 0.4A when powered from 230VAC.

So, you can use the smaller power cable.

Comment: Thank you very much. I looked at the specs so often and never saw it.